# Raytracing: mirror reflection in object coordinates

Tags: math, raytracing

I'm having fun writing my own raytracer. I'm doing correctly a metal surface ray reflection on world coordinates:

- I have an incident ray in world coords, defined by `origin_point` and `direction_vector`;
- `inverse_transform_matrix * origin_point` gives me the ray origin in object space, and `inverse_transform_matrix ^ direction_vector` gives me the ray direction in object space (with `^` I mean matrix-vector multiplication with no translation).
- Now I do my calculations to get the hit point and hit normal vector, in object space;
- `transform_matrix * hit_point` gives me the hit point in world coords, and `(inverse_transform_matrix_transposed ^ hit_normal).normalized()` gives me the `world_normal_vector` with length 1 in world coordinates.

Now I can have the mirror-like reflected ray direction in world coords: `reflected_dir_vector = direction_vector - 2*(direction_vector • world_normal_vector) * world_normal_vector` (`•` is the dot product). The hit point in world coords is the origin point of my new ray.

Now I can check the angles of the incoming ray and reflected ray respect to the normal (still in world coordinates) using the cross product and they are equal; I can also export my vectors in a wavefront file, load it in Blender and see with my eyes that everything is fine - the angles between the vectors are ok and all the vectors are on the same plane. My eyes aren't a math proof but the rendered picture with these calculation is fine.

BUT:

I'd like to calculate the reflected ray direction in objected coordinates and after that go back to world coordinates, due to the way I want my code to work.

I can calculate the reflected vector direction in object space just like before but using object coords: `reflected_dir_vector = object_coords_direction_vector - 2*(object_coords_direction_vector • object_coords_normal_vector) * object_coords_normal_vector`. Now I don't get what matrix I should use to move this vector to world coordinates; I tried all my direct, inverse and trasponsed transformation matrices but all of them gives me a wrong reflected direction.

Where's my error?

I'm not showing code to not to make and excessively long post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your implementation of multiplication is correct you should use your local to global matrix to transform the reflection from local to world space. You should do: `transformation_matrix ^ reflection_vector`. Also make sure that your vectors are normalised.

transforming a normalised vector does not yield a normalised result.